# How to solve NullPointer Exception?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I have an application with 3 tabs (Fragments) in tab 1 I have an Async method like this

```
 public class getUserGroupAsync extends AsyncTask<JSONObject,Void,JSONObject>{
        String resp;
        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(JSONObject... params) {

            JSONObject paramObj = new JSONObject();

            try {
                getToken();
                method = "hostgroup.get";
                paramObj.put("output","groupids");

                response = sendJsonRequest.getResponse(method,paramObj,token);
                resp = response.getString("result");
            }

            catch (JSONException e) {
                System.out.println("Error "+e.getMessage());
            }





        }
    }
```

When I switch from tab 1 to another tab and after that I go back to Tab 1 I want to reload the Async task.

I tried like this:

```
   public class ClientActivity extends  ActionBarActivity{
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      public void onPageSelected(int position) {




                   if (position == 0){


                        systemStatus.new getUserGroupAsync().execute();


                   }





                }
    }
}
```

But I get a NullPointerException ?
Any help please ?

Comment: Please post the stacktrace of your Exception.

Comment: Also, does this code compile? systemStatus.new getUserGroupAsync().execute(); does not appear to be correct syntax.

Comment: My answer didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

try putting your code in the onResume method of your fragment1

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    new getUserGroupAsync().execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume from your code that the `getUserGroupAsync` Class is inside another class called `systemStatus`? It is difficult to tell, because classes typically have the first letter capitalised (`GetUserGroupAsync` and `SystemStatus`) where objects have their first letter in lower case (`getUserGroupAsync` and `systemStatus`).

If getUserGroupAsync is inside a class named systemStatus, which is accessed via a tab, then the best method would be to refresh your data this way:

```
class systemStatus extends Fragment {
    private getUserGroupAsync asyncTask = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       if (asyncTask == null) {
           asyncTask = new getUserGroupAsync();
           asyncTask.execute();
       }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume () {
           asyncTask = new getUserGroupAsync();
           asyncTask.execute();
       }

    //...
    public class getUserGroupAsync extends AsyncTask<JSONObject,Void,JSONObject>{
    //etc...
```